# Realm for React Native - case insensitive search

Tags: react-native, realm

How do I use the filtered function to make a case insensitive search?

```
var query = 'david';
var filteredNames = names.filtered('name == $0', query);
```

This only returns results where name is 'david', not 'David'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Case insensitive search is supported as of v0.11.0. To search case insensitive you append `[c]` to your operator eg:

```
name ==[c] 'jerry'
name BEGINSWITH[c] 'a'
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. I hope you find a way to add it soon as it is a vital feature for my project - and probably others too :)